# $broadcast only firing when limited characters used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-broadcast

Trying to use Angular's `$broadcast`, when I test it and use the string 'hi', and watch for it in a sibling controller, it works fine, like so:

```
//first controller
app.controller('colourKeyCtrl', colourKeyCtrl);
function colourKeyCtrl($scope, $timeout, patents, patentPhasesService) {
    vm.$onInit = function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('hi');
    }
}

//second controller
app.controller('graphDonutCtrl', graphDonutCtrl);
function graphDonutCtrl($scope, patents, patentPhasesService, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on('hi', function(event, opt){
       alert('hello there')
    })    
}
```

As soon as I change the string to anything else, such as `phaseChange`, it fails to invoke the `$on` method in the second controller. Not sure why. I have attempted to wrap `$broadcast` in a `$timeout` method but that hasn't resolved the issue.

***Question***

Am I using `$broadcast` in the wrong manner or is my syntax incorrect?

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/dashboard/views/dashboard.htm',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'
        },
        'colourkeywidget@dashboard': {
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/dashboard/views/ui-views/colour-key-widget.htm',
            controller: 'colourKeyCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'                
        },
        'graphdonutwidget@dashboard': {
            controller: 'graphDonutCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',                
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/dashboard/views/ui-views/graph-donut-widget.htm',         
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: `$broadcast` starts at the current scope and goes down to child scopes. `$emit` starts at the current scope and goes up the scope chain.
There is no event dispatch method that goes to sibling scopes. You'd need to `$emit` up to the parent and handle the event there to `$broadcast` it back down.

Comment: Thank you. That was the one, though, any idea why it was working at one point? With broadcasting 'hi'

Comment: No idea. It shouldn't have ever worked. Perhaps you had the `$broadcast` code in the parent controller at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice! If you want to leave your comment as an answer, I will happily accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$broadcast` starts at the current scope and goes down to child scopes.

`$emit` starts at the current scope and goes up the scope chain.

There is no event dispatch method that goes to sibling scopes.You'd need to `$emit` up to the parent and handle the event there to `$broadcast` it back down.